# How to encode a wrapper type so that it doesn't get nest in a container?

Tags: swift, encoding

Normally if I have a struct like this:

```
struct Box: Codable {
  let id: String

  /// This is an expression (e.g. `x + 3`) rather than a number.
  let height: String
}
```

It would get encoded as JSON as follows:

```
{
  "id": "box1",
  "height": "x + 3"
}
```

The problem is that I want to introduce a new wrapper type `Expression` to make it obvious that I shouldn't be using normal strings in this property:

```
struct Box: Codable {
  let id: String
  let height: Expression
}

struct Expression: Codable {
  let string: String
}
```

The API is now more clear with this wrapper type, but the JSON is now nested:

```
{
  "id": "box1",
  "height": {
    "string": "x + 3"
  }
}
```

I'd like to remove this nesting so it looks like this again:

```
{
  "id": "box1",
  "height": "x + 3"
}
```

---

I'd prefer not to override anything on `Box` since:

1. Box may have many other properties and I'd rather not have to maintain the encode/decode functions manually.
2. Anywhere else that `Expression` is used should benefit from this non-nested container behavior without me writing more Codable boilerplate.

Therefore, I'd like to only modify `Expression`, and get it to output its encoded data without introducing an extra container.

---

I tried using `container.superEncoder()` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461744/swift-codable-how-to-encode-top-level-data-into-nested-container), but that kept the same hierarchy and renamed `"string"` with `"super"`.

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that the standard implementation of Codable is as follows:

```
extension Expression: Codable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .string)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(self.string, forKey: .string)
  }

  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case string
  }
}
```

Notice how it adds a container insider the encoder/decoder.

Instead, what you want to do is interact with the encoder/decoder that is sent directly:

```
extension Expression: Codable {
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    try string.encode(to: encoder)
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    string = try String(from: decoder)
  }
}
```

This will encode/decode the object as though the custom wrapper doesn't exist:

```
{
  "id": "box1",
  "height": "x + 3"
}
```